# How can I insert values into table like Bulk Insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005

I have values like

```
  string a,b;
  a= "1,2,3,4";
  b="admin";
```

I am passing a and b to SP and I want to save it in DB like

```
a   b
1  admin
2  admin
3  admin
4  admin
```

How can I do this? Can someone give me some ideas on how to do it? 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't have a concept of arrays, so this gets a bit interesting.
Pass a list as a string parameter:

```
DECLARE @INSTR as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @INSTR = '2,3,177,'
DECLARE @SEPERATOR as VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
SET @SEPERATOR = ','
WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO myTable (a, b) VALUES (@VALUE, 'admin')
END
```